# Featuring product based on the Store with a library cart CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I try to create an online store using CodeIgniter application with a library cart, but I have a problem when displaying data by category id how to solve this problem?

Example

Store A

```
 ID   |       Name     |   Qty  |   Store   |
 ---- | -------------- | ------ | --------- |
 1    |   Nokia 1      |    1   |  Store A  | 
 2    |   Samsung xxx  |    1   |  Store A  | 
 3    |   Nokia 2      |    3   |  Store A  |
```

Store B

```
 ID   |       Name     |   Qty  |   Store   |
 ---- | -------------- | ------ | --------- |
 4    |   Nokia 6      |    1   |  Store B  | 
 5    |   Samsung xx   |    1   |  Store B  |
```

Store C

```
 ID   |       Name     |   Qty  |   Store   |
 ---- | -------------- | ------ | --------- |
 6    |   Nokia 9      |    1   |  Store C  |
```

Add to cart,  Controllers

```
function add_to_rent($id_product) {
    $produk = $this->product_model->get_id($id_product);
    $data = array(
                'id' => $produk->id_product,
                'name' => $produk->name_product,
                'qty' => 1,
                'store' =>  $produk->id_outlet
            );      
    $this->cart->insert($data);
    redirect($this->agent->referrer()); 
}
```

View cart

```
<?php
    foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $product){ 
?>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name product</th>
            <th>Qty</th>                        
            <th>Store</th>
        /tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product['id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product['name'];?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $product['qty'];?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $product['store'];?></td>    
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: whats the problem are you getting?
Also correct the variable $produk

Comment: have a look here, may be you can solve your problem, also please tell what problem are you facing?
https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-shopping-cart/

Comment: yes sorry I was wrong to write the script, its problems if it can combine the product on a cart based store?